# ¿Cómo puedo instalar tensorflow_text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Intento reprdoducir el [notebook sobre Google Multilingual Universal Encoder](http://Cross-Lingual%20Similarity%20and%20Semantic%20Search%20Engine%20with%20TF-Hub%20Multilingual%20Universal%20Encoder). Sin embargo al descargar las librerias necesidas como `tensorflow_text`:

```
%%capture
#@title Setup Environment
# Install the latest Tensorflow version.
!pip3 install tensorflow_text
```

o

```
!python -m pip install tensorflow_text
```

Me salé jupyter:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-399dd4157896> in <module>
      8 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
      9 import tensorflow_hub as hub
---> 10 from tensorflow_text import SentencepieceTokenizer
     11 import sklearn.metrics.pairwise
     12 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_text'
```

Intenté instalarlo con `python -m pip install tensorflow-text`, pero me da:

```
(seg_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>python -m pip install tensorflow-text
Collecting tensorflow-text
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Tambien intenté en `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

```
(seg_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment> conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.


C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>set "KERAS_BACKEND="

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>python C:\Users\antoi\.conda\envs\seg_env\etc\keras\load_config.py  1>temp.txt

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>del temp.txt

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>if errorlevel 1 (
ver  1>nul
 set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
 python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
)

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>SET platform=

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=" )

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>if "" == "" (
ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
 GOTO End
)
"WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
The system cannot find the batch label specified - End
```

## Actualizacion

Hicé `python -m pip install tensorflow-text` en el terminal y `!python -m pip install tensorflow-text`. El primero me devuelve:

```
(seg_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>python -m pip install tensorflow-text
Collecting tensorflow-text
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

El segundo no me devuelve nada en el notebook. Así que no estoy seguro de que haya subido nada.

Luego estoy tratando de cargarlo en el cuaderno.:

```
from tensorflow_text import SentencepieceTokenizer
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-399dd4157896> in <module>
      8 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
      9 import tensorflow_hub as hub
---> 10 from tensorflow_text import SentencepieceTokenizer
     11 import sklearn.metrics.pairwise
     12 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_text'
```

Y, con `tensorflow-text`:

```
  File "<ipython-input-53-9d3d22c2bd52>", line 10
    from tensorflow-text import SentencepieceTokenizer
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

## Documentacion

Parece que:

> TensorFlow Text requires TensorFlow 2.0, and is fully compatible with
>   eager mode and graph mode.

Entonces hicé `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`:

Pero me devuelve:

```
Successfully built wrapt gast opt-einsum
ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 has requirement grpcio>=1.24.3, but you'll have grpcio 1.23.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: oauthlib, urllib3, chardet, idna, requests, requests-oauthlib, cachetools, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, rsa, google-auth, google-auth-oauthlib, tensorboard, wrapt, gast, opt-einsum, google-pasta, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow
  Attempting uninstall: tensorboard
    Found existing installation: tensorboard 1.13.1
    Uninstalling tensorboard-1.13.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorboard-1.13.1
  Attempting uninstall: gast
    Found existing installation: gast 0.3.3
    Uninstalling gast-0.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled gast-0.3.3
  Attempting uninstall: tensorflow-estimator
    Found existing installation: tensorflow-estimator 1.13.0
    Uninstalling tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0
  Attempting uninstall: tensorflow
    Found existing installation: tensorflow 1.13.2
    Uninstalling tensorflow-1.13.2:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-1.13.2
Successfully installed cachetools-4.0.0 chardet-3.0.4 gast-0.2.2 google-auth-1.11.2 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.1 google-pasta-0.1.8 idna-2.8 oauthlib-3.1.0 opt-einsum-3.1.0 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 requests-2.22.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 rsa-4.0 tensorboard-2.1.0 tensorflow-2.1.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.1.0 urllib3-1.25.8 wrapt-1.12.0

(seg_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation>python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Dec  6 2019, 07:03:06) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow_text import SentencepieceTokenizer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_text'
```

Entonces traté de installarlo:

```
(seg_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation>python -m pip install tensorflow-text
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text
```

Comment: Qué versión de Python y TensorFlow tienes?

Comment: @Name_Not_Found Actualicé con las versiones. Pero supongo que el problema esta que utiliso Python 3.7

Comment: Tienes las versión 2.1.0 de TensorFlow?

Comment: @Name_Not_Found 1.15.1, lo anadi en la resputesta. Hay todas las versiones

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás usando la versión `1.15.1` de `TensorFlow`, de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/tensorflow_text/intro) de `tensorflow-text`, `tensorflow-text` necesita como mínimo la versión `2.0` de `TensorFlow`, te suguiero que primero actualices `pip` a la última versión con el siguiente comando:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

Luego actualiza `TensorFlow` a la versión `2.0` o superior de la siguiente manera:

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

y posteriormente, instales `tensorflow-text` con el siguiente comando:

`pip install tensorflow-text`

#### Edit:

Por aparentes problemas en los binarios de `Windows` que se pueden observar en este [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/44) activo, no es posible instalar `tensorflow-text` en `Windows`. Esta solución es solo válida para `Linux` y `MacOS`.

Comment: Muchas gracias para su respuesta. Actualicé mi pregunta porque tuve un error durante la instalación que no pareció impedirlo: `ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 has requirement grpcio>=1.24.3, but you'll have grpcio 1.23.0 which is incompatible.`. Sin embargo, todavía no puedo instalar tensorflow. `No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text`

Comment: Qué te sale cuando intentas `pip install tensorflow-text`? Ya que por lo que veo estás usando un `virtual env`, y si haces `python -m pip install tensorflow-text` cabe la posibilidad de que estés tratando de instalar el modulo en otra versión de Python diferente a la  `3.6.7`.

Comment: Con `pip install tensorflow-text` me salé `ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text`

Comment: Hola de nuevo, investigando un poco más acerca del problema ya que las recomendaciones que te he dado deberían ser suficientes, me he encontrado con esta [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/89) de `tensorflow-text` en el que explican que están teniendo problemas con los binarios de `tensorflow-text` para `Windows`, pero en este otro [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/44), los problemas con sus binarios siguen estando presentes, en el [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/2.0.0rc0/#files) no están los binarios de `tensorflow-text` para `Windows`.

Comment: La solución que he dado a tu pregunta ha funcionado en mi máquina Linux por lo que no experimenté ningún problema como este: `ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text`, por lo que podría recomendarte que uses un contenedor de `docker` que tenga una imagén de `Python`, ya que estos contenedores corren sobre `Linux`, y ejecutar tu código en ese contenedor (con todas las dependencias previamente instaladas).

Answer (score 0):

La librería es `tensorflow-text`, con guión en lugar de guión bajo

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Sin embargo, no me devuelve nada del cuaderno. Así que no estoy seguro de haber descargado nada. Todavía tengo el error `ModuleNotFoundError`.